# Test requests authentication

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have this function that downloads files from our companies repository, everything works fine, the problem is that when an incorrect username or password in inserted it doesn't notify me of that, it just downloads a 0 KB file and fails when it tries to extract it.
Is there any way i can make sure that the password/username is correct? or at least know that when an error happens that it's because of that?

Here's the function, it's part of a larger script with tkinter GUI.

```
def download_file(dl_url, local_save_path):
    dnl_sum = 1024
    local_filename = dl_url.split('/')[-1]
    complete_name = os.path.join(local_save_path, local_filename)
    # Get file size
    r = requests.head(dl_url, auth=(username.get(), password.get()), verify=False)
    try:
        dl_file_size = int(r.headers['content-length'])
        file_size.set(str(int(int(r.headers['content-length']) * (10 ** -6))) + "MB")
        c = 1
    except KeyError:
        c = 0
        pass
    r = requests.get(dl_url, stream=True, auth=(username.get(), password.get()), verify=False)
    while True:
        try:
            with open(complete_name, 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
                    if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                        f.write(chunk)
                        f.flush()
                        if c == 1:
                            download_perc.set(percentage(dl_file_size, dnl_sum))
                        elif c == 0:
                            print(dnl_sum)
                        dnl_sum = os.path.getsize(complete_name)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            continue
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to validate that you got a 200 OK response before downloading. If the wrong username or password was sent, the server will probably respond with a 403 (Forbidden) or 401 (Unauthorized) status code instead.

You can check the [`Response.status_code` attribute](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.status_code):

```
if r.status_code == 200:
    # successful, download response to a file
```

or you can explicitly test for 40x codes:

```
if r.status_code in (401, 403):
    # access denied, handle this and don't download
```

or you can ask the response object to raise an exception if the response code is not a successful one, by calling the [`Response.raise_for_status()` method](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status):

```
r.raise_for_status()  # raises exception if a 4xx or 5xx status was returned
```

See [*Response Status Codes*](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes) in the *Quickstart* documentation.